# How to create a full width bar in ionic?

Tags: html

I have no idea how to design like this [Created by wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q0Ac.png)

I want my bar to fill like the blue color, which touch the both end of the screen.

But I not able to do it, I only can do like this[real design application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcKqK.png)

How to do like that ??

This is my code

```
<div>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title style="text-align:center;">Reporting Problem</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</div>
```

Comment: Normally you should've shared your code too, but because you're working in ionic which has built in styles and elements I'm gonna give you a workaround for your issue by seeing the images.

Comment: So you need to add negative margins(left and right) for that black bar of yours(`ion-title` or whatever tag it has); that's because all your content it's wrapped in an element which has `padding left and right` around `10 -15px`

Comment: @sTx sorry, I'm new to stack overflow, may I know that what you mean by shared my code ? means all of the code ? I am new to it hope that you can help me figure out. 

And after I put the padding left negative margins it still have the same problem..

Comment: I mean that you need to share all relevant code(html, css, javascript) for your problem, can also provide an working example with your problem

Comment: but you are using ionic so it's hard to replicate the problem here

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I get it. I will provide it next time when I ask a question. Thanks a lot !! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my example below. If you comment `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `nav` you will see that `nav` actual size is smaller, because `wrapper`(parent) has a `padding: 20px`.

Hope you know how to use browser's inspect element.

```css
.wrapper{
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid silver;
 padding: 20px;
}
nav{
  background-color: #0095ff;
  coloR: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
.wrapper>div{
  width: 85px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>Navbar here</nav>
  <div>Child1</div>
  <div style="  margin-left: 5px;">Child2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks !! @sTx it works now !! love you so much..it border me the whole morning..thanks !